# Compound child view not shown inside custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

I'm coding a ring menu that is going to put together several different types of view, which will have all the same size. The thing is that it works perfectly with native views, like `ImageView`, but when I try to put a custom labeled image view, it simply doesn't appear int the custom ViewGroup. It's also worth mentioning that when this view is declared in the XML file, outside de custom `ViewGroup` it is shown just fine, but as soon as I put it inside the `ViewGroup`, or declare it programatically, it vanishes. My guess is that I'm doing something weong inside the `onLayout` method, but I can't put my finger on it, since all coordinates and view sizes are correct according to the Log.

The XML file for the CompoundView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ropeiconselector"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WWWWWWWWWWWW"
    android:background="@color/button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/header"
    android:padding="8dp"
    />
```

The code for the CompoundView (I omitted some unimportant methods)

```
public class CircularLabeledImageView extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener {


ImageView headerView;
TextView labelView;

boolean isOpen = false;

String[] itemDesc;

int position;
int size;

int maxLabelWidth = 100;
int minLabelWidth = 20;

final Handler timeHandler = new Handler();
Runnable toggleTimer;

public CircularLabeledImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
```

//EDIT Methhod called
        initView(context);

```
}

public CircularLabeledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView(context);
}

public CircularLabeledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initView(context);
}

private void initView(Context context){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandabletextimageview, this);

    headerView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.header);
    labelView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.label);

    labelView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.backgroundMenuContents);

    headerView.setOnClickListener(this);

    itemDesc = new String[]{"Item A","Item B", "Item C","Quantos itens"};
    size = itemDesc.length;

    toggleTimer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toggle();
        }
    };

    this.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (isOpen) {
                toggle();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

The code for the custom ViewGroup

```
public class RingListMenu extends ViewGroup implements View.OnClickListener {

boolean isOpen = true;
int headerSize= 90;
int childSize= 80;
int radiusInit = 150;
int childInitSize = 80;
int radius = 150;
int padding;

DPoint center = new DPoint();

float startingAngle= 2;

DPoint click0;
DPoint clickIni;
DPoint clickFinal;
final static float SENSIBILITY = 10f;
final static float FRICTION = 0.00001f;
final static float MAXVELOCITY = 0.06f;
final static long TOGGLE_DURATION = 300;
private VelocityTracker vTracker = null;
boolean isScrolling;

ImageView circleView;
OnItemClickListener listener = null;

public RingListMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
    {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    TypedArray at = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.RingListMenu);
    childInitSize = childSize = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_childSize, 0);
    radiusInit = radius = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_circleRadius, 0);
    headerSize = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_headerSize, 0);
    padding = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_padding, 0);
}

public RingListMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
    {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    TypedArray at = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.RingListMenu);
    childInitSize = childSize = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_childSize, 0);
    radiusInit = radius = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_circleRadius, 0);
    headerSize = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_headerSize, 0);
    padding = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_padding, 0);
}

public RingListMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
    {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    TypedArray at = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RingListMenu);
    childInitSize = childSize = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_childSize, 0);
    radiusInit = radius = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_circleRadius, 0);
    headerSize = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_headerSize, 0);
    padding = at.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RingListMenu_padding, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    Log.d("RingList", "Calling Ring list onLayout" + childSize + " " + radius + " " + headerSize);

    float angle = (float) (2*Math.PI)/(getChildCount()-1);
    center.x = padding+headerSize/2;
    center.y = padding+headerSize/2;
    float childX;
    float childY;

    //radius = (float) (getChildCount()*(minSpacing+2*childSize)/(2*Math.PI));

    for (int i = 1; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);

        childX = (float) (center.x + radius * Math.cos(startingAngle + i * angle));
        childY = (float) (center.y + radius * Math.sin(startingAngle + i * angle));

        child.layout((int) (childX - childSize / 2), (int) (childY - childSize / 2),
                (int) (childX + childSize / 2), (int) (childY + childSize / 2));
    }

    View header = getChildAt(0);
    header.setX(padding);
    header.setY(padding);
    header.layout(padding, padding, padding + headerSize, padding + headerSize);
}

@Override
public void addView(View child) {
    child.setTag(getChildCount());
    super.addView(child);
    child.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

}

And finally, the declaration part:

```
    RingListMenu ring = (RingListMenu) findViewById(R.id.ring);
    CircularLabeledImageView ViewA = new CircularLabeledImageView(this);
    ring.addView(ViewA);
```